# find sum of the count for the latest snapshot in pandas

Tags: pandas

i have a below df and want to calculate sum of a group by taking last snapshot:

```
product  desc   id month_year count

car      ford   1 2019-01     20
car      ford   1 2019-02     20
car      ford   1 2019-04     40
car      ford   2 2019-04     30
car      ford   2 2019-04     30
car      ford   2 2019-04     60
```

and find output as

```
df.groupby(["product", "desc"]. ?

product  desc  count_overall
car      ford  100
```

which is for id 1 take last count order by desc month_year which is 40 and similarly for 2 it is 60 which makes the total as 100

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need the id as well to get the `last` value of count

```
s=df.groupby(["product", "desc","id"])['count'].last().sum(level=[0,1]).to_frame('count_overall').reset_index()
Out[171]: 
  product  desc  count_overall
0     car  ford            100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `drop_duplicates` given the data is sorted by date already:

```
(df.drop_duplicates(['product','desc','id'], keep='last')
   .groupby(['product','desc'])['count'].sum()
)
```

Output:

```
product  desc
car      ford    100
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

we can use `groupby` with `agg` with sort_values to get the last occurance of count.

first we transform your date into a proper datetime

```
df['month_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month_year'],format='%Y-%m')

new_df = df.sort_values("count").groupby(["product", "desc", "id"]).agg(
    date_max=("month_year", max), count=("count", "last")
)
```

---

```
print(new_df)

                  date_max  count
product desc id                  
car     ford 1  2019-04-01     40
             2  2019-04-01     60
```

from here you can just do a simple sum

```
print(new_df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum())


              count
product desc       
car     ford    100
```